# How to link to latest build on Visual Studio Team Services

Tags: azure, tfs, build, azure-devops, tfsbuild

Latest Team Foundation Server and Visual Studio Team Services can generate a build status badge.

BTW, I don't find how can I link it to a public build details of latest build (or even other past builds).

For example, my build status badge is this one:

[image: trackerdog build badge]

For example, I've another old project hosted on GitHub and it has CI with Travis, and I both have a build badge and a build summary: https://travis-ci.org/mfidemraizer/joopl/builds

I'm just asking for getting this summary on Visual Studio Team Services.

Comment: I would like to know why this question is unclear. It's very clear: **with other build systems with open source project hosting support like GitHub, you can see a summary of latest builds and their logs**. For example, TravisCI has it. See some other project that has CI on Travis: https://travis-ci.org/mfidemraizer/joopl/builds

Comment: I've updated my question to reflect that extra information for those that could consider it as being unclear...................................

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to do this, the Build Badge only provide an image to show the build status for now.

There are several feature requests submitted on VSTS User Voice, you can vote them:

[When clicking a badge, it should direct me to my visual studio build history instead of just directing me to an image](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services/suggestions/13136172-when-clicking-a-badge-it-should-direct-me-to-my-v)

[Expose more granular, better badges. (With test results)](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services/suggestions/13135776-expose-more-granular-better-badges-with-test-re)

Comment: BTW, it's incredible how you added this feature and there's no public build summary. I understand that this badge, then, was added for internal development teams :/

Answer (score 1):

It would be possible to [create an extension](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/extensions/overview) that reaches into the latest build details. For example, you could create a build task that posts the details somewhere.

Comment: Yeah this would be a nice idea

Answer (score 1):

Update for 2019: I don't know when this was added, but there is now a formatted markdown link available that will click through to the latest build. You can use it anywhere that supports markdown syntax (Project welcome pages, repository README files, dashboard widgets, comments, etc.).

It uses the format:

```
[![Build status](<project url>/_apis/build/status/<build name>)](<project url>/_build/latest?definitionId=<build id>)
```

You can find it at the bottom of the `Options` tab in your pipeline build definition.