# How to change TFS/DevOps 2019 configuration to open build/release badges for public access

Tags: azure-devops

I'd like to make the build/release status badges from my on-prem server available to non-TFS users on my corporate intranet. Assuming that this doesn't break my license (maybe a bad assumption), is there a change I can make to the self-hosted site's web.config to allow just these images to be served up to anyone?

I haven't been able to find anything in the MS docs referring to the security of these APIs. 
We haven't made any changes to the default web.config except to add a URL rewrite to HTTPS, so the default authentication is Windows and authorization is any users.

My assumption is that the security is managed entirely within TFS, but it doesn't appear to be defined at this level of granularity. My fear is that I'd need to make everyone Stakeholders, which isn't going to happen due to the cost vs benefit.

We have figured out Windows Authentication in Chrome, so using a "Domain Users" group could be used if that would help.

Here are the patterns used for the badge URLs:
https://myurl.com/MyCollection/TeamProjectName/_apis/build/status/BuildDefName
https://myurl.com/MyCollection/_apis/public/Release/badge/1b04c32b-a1b6-4992-92a3-423eb7e41742/1/1

Ideally, I'd be able to reference these from a "Health" page on our internal wiki (not TFS) and have them be accessible to anyone in our management.

Update: I see in this post that the on-line version is accessible:
[How to link to latest build on Visual Studio Team Services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39039008/how-to-link-to-latest-build-on-visual-studio-team-services)

but the URL pattern is different:
https://mfidemraizer.visualstudio.com/_apis/public/build/definitions/6b21f8d5-b74c-4f26-8e06-f156bd0ab331/1/badge

I'm using a new build definition, so I assume that the on-prem api's aren't the same.